# Why does the staff's solution have a link that works for the register button?

Tags: python, html, flask, cs50

In CS50x's Problem Set 9, why does the staff's solution have a link that works for the register button, while when I click the register button of the version of the code they sent me, it displays a 500 Internal Server Error. Before I tweaked my code some more, I saw a 404 error so I know its not because of some sloppy mistake of mine. Do I need to implement the register webpage by myself or is this just a mistake?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here

Comment: You need to implement the register webpage by yourself, as well as the register function in app.py.